# html5 audio can't find source

Tags: spring, html, jsp, html5-audio

I have added an audio html5 tag with the right source for the audio file.

```
<audio controls="controls"> 
    <source src="/WEB-INF/classes/newAudio.wav" type="audio/wav"/> 
</audio>
```

When I run my spring web application, the player cant find the source. I am using Chrome.

The audio file is created in the location /WEB-INF/classes/newAudio.wav
Should I change the location of this file that is created?

Comment: what error do you get 404 or forbidden?

Comment: are you using spring security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEB-INF is not normally accessible.  Have you tried to move it to another folder?

Comment: I moved it to the <webapp>/sounds/newAudio.wav folder, but I cant access it from there too. In the src I use "/sounds/newAudio.wav". What would be the correct path to use in the src attribute?

Comment: It can be relative or absolute path, relative in this case.  When you load the page with IE or Chrome's developer tools opened to the network panel, you should be able to see what it is trying to load and the status code (e.g. 404)

Answer (score 0):

Put file in your `<webapp>/sounds/newAudio.wav`.

If you are using spring security, add interceptor url in spring security configuration like :

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/sounds/**" filters="none"/>
</security:http>
```